# I'm trying to write an econometric equation and I haven't figured what is wrong with the code in LaTeX

Tags: equations

It is a fairly simple question, it might sound stupid to some, but I am in urgency. The code it is just below:

```
\begin{equation}

\[Y_{it}=\beta_0+\beta_1K_{it}+\sum_f \alpha_fR_{fit}^T+\sum_g \phi_gR_{git}+\varepsilon_{it}\]

\end{equation}
```

So why does it not work? For instance, the equation code does not fit the whole line, but even when I type `\\` it still does not work.

Comment: Remove `\[` and `\]` from those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\[` and `\]` inside `equation` environment. Remove them. Also don't leave blank lines inside the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    Y_{it}=\beta₀+\beta₁K_{it}+∑_f \alpha_fR_{fit}^T+∑_g \phi_gR_{git}+\varepsilon_{it}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want un-numbered equation, then use

```
\[
Y_{it}=\beta₀+\beta₁K_{it}+∑_f \alpha_fR_{fit}^T+∑_g \phi_gR_{git}+\varepsilon_{it}
\]
```

The `equation` environment doesn't tolerate `\\` inside. If you want to break the lines inside equation, use the environments `align` `align*` and friends provided by `amsmath` package.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    Y_{it}&=\beta₀+\beta₁K_{it}+∑_f \alpha_fR_{fit}^T+∑_g \phi_gR_{git} \notag\\
          &\phantom{{}=}{}+{}\varepsilon_{it}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Or better `multline`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{multline}
    Y_{it}=\beta₀+\beta₁K_{it}+∑_f \alpha_fR_{fit}^T+∑_g \phi_gR_{git} \notag\\
          +\varepsilon_{it}
  \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Since this particular equation fits within one line, these may not be necessary.